# Add configure product in Cart using Magento 2 API facing an issue

Tags: magento2, api, addtocart, rest-api

> Here's the url

```
http://<magento host>/rest/default/V1/carts/mine/items
```

> Method POST

**Headers**

```
Authentication :: Bearer <customer token>
Content-Type :: application/json
```

> Body json data

```
{
  "cartItem": {
    "sku": "HKrh15hc",
    "qty": 1,
    "quote_id": "23",
    "product_option": {
      "extension_attributes": {
        "configurable_item_options": [
          {
            "option_id": "93",
            "option_value": 50
          },
          {
            "option_id": "141",
            "option_value": 169
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "extension_attributes": {}
  }
}
```

> **I have cross checked the attributes and options value id and also a Quote id**

**Response**

> {
>       "message": "Could not save quote",
>       "trace": "#0 /var/www/html/rb-dev/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/QuoteRepository/SaveHandler.php(82):
>   Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\CartItemPersister->save(Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Interceptor),
>   Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item))\n#1
>   /var/www/html/rb-dev/generated/code/Magento/Quote/Model/QuoteRepository/SaveHandler/Interceptor.php(24):
>   Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository\SaveHandler->save(Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Interceptor))\n#2
>   /var/www/html/rb-dev/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/QuoteRepository.php(181):
>   Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository\SaveHandler\Interceptor->save(Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Interceptor))\n#3
>   /var/www/html/rb-dev/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58):
>   Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository->save(Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Interceptor))\n#4
>   /var/www/html/rb-dev/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138):
>   Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository\Interceptor->___callParent('save',
>   Array)\n#5
>   /var/www/html/rb-dev/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153):
>   Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Interceptor))\n#6
>   /var/www/html/rb-dev/generated/code/Magento/Quote/Model/QuoteRepository/Interceptor.php(78):
>   Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository\Interceptor->___callPlugins('save',
>   Array, Array)\n#7
>   /var/www/html/rb-dev/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote/Item/Repository.php(92):
>   Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository\Interceptor->save(Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Interceptor))\n#8
>   [internal function]:
>   Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\Repository->save(Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item))\n#9
>   /var/www/html/rb-dev/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(330):
>   call_user_func_array(Array, Array)\n#10
>   /var/www/html/rb-dev/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(239):
>   Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->processApiRequest()\n#11
>   /var/www/html/rb-dev/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58):
>   Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#12
>   /var/www/html/rb-dev/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138):
>   Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch',
>   Array)\n#13
>   /var/www/html/rb-dev/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153):
>   Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#14
>   /var/www/html/rb-dev/generated/code/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/Interceptor.php(39):
>   Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch',
>   Array, Array)\n#15
>   /var/www/html/rb-dev/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135):
>   Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#16
>   /var/www/html/rb-dev/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(24):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()\n#17
>   /var/www/html/rb-dev/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()\n#18
>   /var/www/html/rb-dev/index.php(39):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))\n#19
>   {main}" }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below collection which have create cart , Add simple and configurable product into the cart API which worked for me.

https://www.getpostman.com/collections/a7900127aac366535a20